# map/set iterator not incrementable in std::map

Tags: c++, std, stdmap

When `it` is the last iteration of the loop, upon that iteration ending this error will be thrown.

```
std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Entity>> entities;
typedef std::map<std::shared_ptr<Entity>,std::vector<std::pair<std::shared_ptr<Entity>,const MTV*>>> colmap;
```

```
std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Entity>>::iterator it;
for(it = entities.begin();it!=entities.end();++it){
    std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Entity>>::iterator it2;
    for(it2 = entities.begin();it2!=entities.end();++it2){
        MTV* mtv = new MTV(1,sf::Vector2f(1,0));
        collisions[it->second].push_back(std::make_pair(it2->second,mtv));
    }
}
```

Comment: May I suggest using `typedef` to shorten the `map` type?

Comment: hehe. That would probably be helpful

Comment: What is the definition of `entities`?

Comment: Also consider using `++it` instead of `it++` so it doesn't have to create a copy of the iterator.

Comment: Entities: `std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Entity>> entities;`

Comment: Does `hasCollided` increment the iterator it is given as argument? Also: Have you tried to run the code in a debugger to identify the line where the message is generated?

Comment: You'd expect `it->second == it->second` to almost always be true... Did you mean `it2->second == it->second`?

Comment: The only reason I can think of that an iterator would suddenly become uniteratable is that the entry it points to has been removed from the map. Could one of the functions you call when you detect a collision end up doing that?

Comment: rici: all the related code is there. The only other functions that are called are getters as far as I can tell

Comment: Maybe you could find out more if you enforced const here (e.g. `hasCollided` seems not to change the state of the Entity) and compared the `entities` map in each iteration to the state before the loop.

Comment: Edited with simplified problem. Apologies for not doing this earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way the iterator could suddenly become unincrementable from the code shown. There must be some other code after which is causing the error.